# Java, Change label Text on 1 of 4 panels created from the same panel declaration

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have Four Panels being dynamically created from a single panel "Mold" each panel has different information on it being set from an array. 
Problem is that when the information updates only the last panel in the set changes.

Example: there is a MovesLeft label that shows obviously the number of moves left. As the number goes down the number listed for that player should change, each player having their own panel. Currently only the last panel's Moveleft Label changes and changes for any player who moves not just the last Player. So if Player 1 uses up all his moves it will show 0 on Player 4's panel rather than on player 1's Panel.

Question: is there a way for me to specify which of the four instances of the label I want to change so that the correct player's info gets updated?

Panel Set up

```
    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    //panel.add(filler);
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    name = new JLabel(minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getName());
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(name, c);

    icon = new JLabel(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getIcon());
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(icon, c);

    lblClass = new JLabel("Class:");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    panel.add(lblClass, c);

    pClass = new JLabel(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getclass());
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(pClass, c);

    lblRole = new JLabel("Role:");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 4;
    panel.add(lblRole, c);

    role = new JLabel(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getRole());
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 4;
    panel.add(role, c);

    dash = new JLabel("--------------------STATS--------------------");
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 5;
    panel.add(dash, c);

    lblStr = new JLabel("Strengh:");
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 6;
    panel.add(lblStr, c);

    str = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getStr()));
    //c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 6;
    panel.add(str, c);

    lblDex = new JLabel("Dexterity:");
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 7;
    panel.add(lblDex, c);

    dex = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getDex()));
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 7;
    panel.add(dex, c);

    lblEnd = new JLabel("Endurance:");
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 8;
    panel.add(lblEnd, c);

    end = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getEnd()));
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 8;
    panel.add(end, c);

    lblDex = new JLabel("Wisdom:");
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 9;
    panel.add(lblDex, c);

    wiz = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getWis()));
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 3;
    c.gridy = 9;
    panel.add(wiz, c);

    lblHp = new JLabel("HP: ");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 10;
    panel.add(lblHp, c);


    health = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getHp()));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 10;
    panel.add(health, c);

    lblMoves = new JLabel("Moves Left: ");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 11;
    panel.add(lblMoves, c);

    movesLeft = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
            MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getMoves()));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 11;
    panel.add(movesLeft, c);

    dash = new JLabel("--------------------SKILLS--------------------");
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 12;
    panel.add(dash, c);

    lblSkill1 = new JLabel("Skill 1:");
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 13;
    panel.add(lblSkill1, c);

    skill1 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill1());
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 13;
    panel.add(skill1, c);

    lblSkill2 = new JLabel("Skill 2:");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 14;
    panel.add(lblSkill2, c);

    skill2 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill2());
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 14;
    panel.add(skill2, c);
    skill2.setEnabled(false);

    lblSkill3 = new JLabel("Skill 3:");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 15;
    panel.add(lblSkill3, c);

    skill3 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill3());
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 15;
    panel.add(skill3, c);
    skill3.setEnabled(false);

    lblSkill4 = new JLabel("Skill 4:");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 16;
    panel.add(lblSkill4, c);

    skill4 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill4());
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 16;
    panel.add(skill4, c);
    skill4.setEnabled(false);        

    skill1.addActionListener(e);
    skill2.addActionListener(e);
    skill3.addActionListener(e);
    skill4.addActionListener(e);

    return panel;
}
```

How the Panel is added to the GUI

```
final JTabbedPane characterInfoPane = new JTabbedPane();
    while (setupPlayerIndex < 4) {
        JComponent panel = makeTextPanel("");
        characterInfoPane.addTab(minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getName(), null, panel,
                "");
        setupPlayerIndex++;
    }
```

how I am currently trying to change the relavent Label where x is the selected Player

```
movesLeft.setText(Integer.toString(MiniRPG.players.get(x).getMoves()));
```

please let me know if addition code is needed to Answer this Question of if it is possible to do what im looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you create a new text pane, you are reassign the variable references.  That is, `movesLeft` will ALWAYS refer to the last panel you created.

Rather then creating the panels in the `makeTextPane`, I would create a custom panel that contained all the information that `makeTextPane` produces.

I would then make setters & getters for all the relevent information you need to get and update.

For example

```
protected class TextPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel name;
    private JLabel icon;
    private JLabel lblClass;
    private JLabel pClass;
    private JLabel lblRole;
    private JLabel role;
    private JLabel lblStr;
    private JLabel str;
    private JLabel lblDex;
    private JLabel dex;
    private JLabel lblEnd;
    private JLabel end;
    private JLabel wiz;
    private JLabel lblHp;
    private JLabel health;
    private JLabel lblMoves;
    private JLabel movesLeft;
    private JLabel lblSkill1;
    private JButton skill1;
    private final JLabel lblSkill2;
    private final JButton skill2;
    private final JLabel lblSkill3;
    private final JButton skill3;
    private final JLabel lblSkill4;
    private final JButton skill4;

    public TextPane() {

        //add(filler);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel dash;

        name = new JLabel(MiniRPG.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getName());
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(name, c);

        icon = new JLabel(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getIcon());
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(icon, c);

        lblClass = new JLabel("Class:");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(lblClass, c);

        pClass = new JLabel(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getclass());
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        add(pClass, c);

        lblRole = new JLabel("Role:");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        add(lblRole, c);

        role = new JLabel(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getRole());
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        add(role, c);

        dash = new JLabel("--------------------STATS--------------------");
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 5;
        add(dash, c);

        lblStr = new JLabel("Strengh:");
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 6;
        add(lblStr, c);

        str = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
                MiniRPG.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getStr()));
        //c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 6;
        add(str, c);

        lblDex = new JLabel("Dexterity:");
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 7;
        add(lblDex, c);

        dex = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
                MiniRPG.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getDex()));
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 7;
        add(dex, c);

        lblEnd = new JLabel("Endurance:");
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 8;
        add(lblEnd, c);

        end = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
                MiniRPG.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getEnd()));
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 8;
        add(end, c);

        lblDex = new JLabel("Wisdom:");
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 9;
        add(lblDex, c);

        wiz = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
                MiniRPG.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getWis()));
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 9;
        add(wiz, c);

        lblHp = new JLabel("HP: ");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 10;
        add(lblHp, c);


        health = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
                MiniRPG.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getHp()));
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 10;
        add(health, c);

        lblMoves = new JLabel("Moves Left: ");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 11;
        add(lblMoves, c);

        movesLeft = new JLabel(Integer.toString(
                MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getMoves()));
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 11;
        add(movesLeft, c);

        dash = new JLabel("--------------------SKILLS--------------------");
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 12;
        add(dash, c);

        lblSkill1 = new JLabel("Skill 1:");
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 13;
        add(lblSkill1, c);

        skill1 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill1());
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 13;
        add(skill1, c);

        lblSkill2 = new JLabel("Skill 2:");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 14;
        add(lblSkill2, c);

        skill2 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill2());
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 14;
        add(skill2, c);
        skill2.setEnabled(false);

        lblSkill3 = new JLabel("Skill 3:");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 15;
        add(lblSkill3, c);

        skill3 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill3());
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 15;
        add(skill3, c);
        skill3.setEnabled(false);

        lblSkill4 = new JLabel("Skill 4:");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 16;
        add(lblSkill4, c);

        skill4 = new JButton(MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getSkill4());
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 16;
        add(skill4, c);
        skill4.setEnabled(false);

        skill1.addActionListener(e);
        skill2.addActionListener(e);
        skill3.addActionListener(e);
        skill4.addActionListener(e);

    }

    public void setMovesLeft(int value) {
        movesLeft.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

}
```

I would then keep a separate reference of each pane when I create it

```
final JTabbedPane characterInfoPane = new JTabbedPane();

TextPane[] textPanes = new TextPane[4];
while (setupPlayerIndex < 4) {
    textPanes[setupPlayerIndex] = new TextPane();
    characterInfoPane.addTab(minirpg.MiniRPG.players.get(setupPlayerIndex).getName(), null, textPanes[setupPlayerIndex],
            "");
    setupPlayerIndex++;
}
```

This would then allow me to change a particular players moves simply by access setter of the `TextPane`

```
textPanes[x].setMovesLeft(MiniRPG.players.get(x).getMoves());
```